# Alternate div width per row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So basically i have this markup

```
<div class="container">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
</div>
```

[image]

How will i be able to have alternate width for the first & second div per row?

I tried `article:nth-child`+ diff stepping to target alternate divs, but i cant find the right combination of stepping

Edit: I really can't edit the HTML structure since this is a WordPress plugin output

Answer (score 10):

You will need to use **[:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)** selector here...

Actually here the pattern is repeating itself after every 4th element...So you will need to taregt `4n`, `4n+1`, `4n+2` and `4n+3`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 20px Verdana;
}

article:nth-child(4n),
article:nth-child(4n+1) {
  width: 25%
}

article:nth-child(4n+2),
article:nth-child(4n+3) {
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
  <article>10</article>
  <article>11</article>
  <article>12</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should apply class for correct adjustment of articles use only two class with width 66% and 33%

Answer (score 1):

1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6

```
article 
{
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width: 30%;
  background: #444;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
article:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f0f;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}
article:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 70%;
}
article:nth-child(4n) {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. With display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap; on ".container" and flex-grow: 1;flex-shrink:1; on article. The article will get the width based on the content.

With flexbox you can do anything, here is a good tutorial https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/